# By Pass Devise Password requirement for single attribute update

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Currently my application is using devise and my users are required to enter a password when updating their profile.

I am working on implementing an additional field to my user's table which remembers their sidebar navigational preference (expanded or collapsed). For testing, I setup a boolean field called "menu_collapsed" which is set to "false" by default.

I am trying to have this value updated to "true" remotely when the user decides to condense the sidebar menu.

**Index**

```
<li><%= link_to('Toggle', toggle_menu_preference_user_path(@user), :method => :put) %></li>
```

**Routes**

```
resources :users do
    member { put :toggle_menu_preference }
end
```

**Users Controller**

```
def toggle_menu_preference
  @user = current_user
  @user.menu_collapsed = !@user.menu_collapsed
  @user.save
end
```

**Application Controller**

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :account_id, :account_name, :password, :password_confirmation) }
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update).concat([:name])
end
```

When I click on the link, it will process the request but I hit a wall with Devise wanting the user to include their password.

Is there a way to by pass the requirement for a password just for this user attribute?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work like a charm!

Tested on local host as well as Heroku

**Application Controller** (added :menu_collapsed) to sanitizer

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
 devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :account_id, :account_name, :password, :password_confirmation) }
 devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update).concat([:name, :menu_collapsed])
end
```

**Routes**

```
resources :users do
  member { put :toggle_menu_preference }
end
```

**User Controller**

```
def menu_preference  
    @user = current_user 
    @user.menu_collapsed = !@user.menu_collapsed
    @user.save
  if @user.menu_collapsed
    render :nothing => true 
   else
     render :nothing => true 
  end  
 end
```

**View**

```
 <%= link_to menu_preference_user_path(current_user), id: "layout-condensed-toggle", remote: true do %>
     <div class="iconset top-menu-toggle-dark"></div>
 <% end %>
```